# ¿Cómo usar los inputs file de react y react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Quería preguntar cómo obtener el file de mi input creado con react-bootstrap, porque cuando intento obtener el file me da el error de como si no existiera el archivo, mi código es el siguiente:

```
<Form.Group controlId='images'>
    <Form.Label>Image</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
            type='file'
            name='images'
            onChange={this.onChange}
         />
</Form.Group>
```

En mi función onChange tengo lo siguiente:

```
onChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.file[0]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es `file[0]` es `files[0]`

```
onChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
}
```